# Find the two values of $k$ for which $2x^3-9x^2+12x-k$ has a double real root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

> Find the two values of $k$ for which $2x^3-9x^2+12x-k$ has a double
>   real root.

I've found one method which is to equate $$2x^3-9x^2+12x-k=2(x-r)^2(x-c)$$

Expanding and equating coefficients I get the system of equations :
\begin{array}
\space 2(c+2r) &=9 \\
2r(2c+r) &=12 \\
-2r^2c&=k \\
\end{array}

Solving this I've found the solutions $k=4,5$

> However, I would like to know if there's some easier solution than the
>   one I've already found, or  in general, if there's any other solution to the
>   problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an easier way. If your polynomial $P_k(x) = 2x^3-9x^2+12x-k$ has a double real root $r$, then $P_k'(r) = 0$.

For such a root, you get $P_k'(r) = 6r^2-18r+12 = 0$, i.e. $r=1$ or $r=2$.

Then you solve $P_k(r)=0$ with respect to $k$. More precisely :

- If $r=1$, one needs $P_k(1)=5-k=0$ i.e. $k=5$.
- If $r=2$, one has $P_k(2)=4-k=0$ i.e. $k=4$.

Comment: How do you find $6r^2-18r+12=0$ from $P(r)=2r^3-9r^2+12 r-k=0$ ?

Comment: @Mr.Y It's $P_k'(r)$, the derivative of $P_k(r)$. Do you know how to compute derivatives?

Comment: @Workaholic Whoops. Thanks for clarifying it (I somehow forget that notation thing for derivatives ....).Fortunately,I know how to compute them.

Comment: The derivative of $P_k$ with respect to $x$ is $6x^2-18x+12$. Then, if $r$ is a double real root of $P_k$, then it must also be a root of $P'_k$. You can see it by writing $P_k(X) = (X-r)^2 \cdot Q(X)$ for some polynomial $Q$.

Comment: +1.  Damn, that's clever.  And obvious in retrospect.  Those two come together more often than perhaps you'd expect.

Comment: I think this works for all non-single roots. Great method.

Answer (score 1):

You could find a relative maximum (or minimum) of f(x) = 2x3−9x2+12x, by considering, it´s derivative then choosing k accordingly. This way you don´need to find the roots explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical background.

In general if $\alpha$ is a multiple root of polynomial $f(x)$ then we can write: $$f(x)=(x-\alpha)^2g(x)$$

Taking the derivative on both sides we find:$$f'\left(x\right)=\left(x-\alpha\right)\left[2g\left(x\right)+\left(x-\alpha\right)g'\left(x\right)\right]$$

Evidently $f'(\alpha)=0$ so $\alpha$ appears to be a root of $f'\left(x\right)$ also.

Comment: Now I  see the reason behind that.Thanks for writing that up .

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From $2x^3-9x^2+12x-k=2(x-r)^2(x-c)$, using Vieta's formulas:

$$-\frac{-9}{2} = r + r + c \implies c = \frac{9}{2} - 2r$$
$$\frac{12}{2} = r \cdot r + r \cdot c + c \cdot r \implies6=r^2 + 2(9/2 - 2r)r$$

hence $6 = r^2 + 9r - 4r^2$ or $3(r^2 - 3r + 2) = 0 \implies r = 1, 2$. Using the remainder theorem, $2(1)^3 - 9(1)^2 + 12(1) - k = 0$ i.e $k =5$, or $2(2)^3 - 9(2)^2 + 12(2) - k = 0$ i.e $k =4$.